# Mac Pro 12-Core: Can Logic Studio Utilize All 12 Cores?

Tags: macos, mac, multi-core, logic-studio

Can Logic Studio 9 utilize all 12 cores of my tricked out Mac Pro?

It's got two Intel Xeon X5670 processors in it.

Answer (score 2):

Logic Studio uses multicore when the action permits. Certain plugins won’t be optimized for Multicore and therefore will run on one core. When you bounce and play real-time, it will definitely use multicore. The more, the merrier.

You can grab a copy of any CPU meter, for example [iStats](http://bjango.com/apps/istatmenus/) and see for yourself.